# How to debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS on device only

Tags: iphone, ipad, device, exc-bad-access

I have some code that returns a struct containing 2 objects (declared as `id`).
When trying to use one of the objects I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and the app crashes. This only happens on the device (ipad) not in the simulator.

I have set NSZombieEnabled to YES, however no information is written to the console.
I don't know if it's a problem that I'm using a workspace in Xcode 4, one project for my app, and another that builds a library which is used in my app. The EXC_BAD_ACCESS is occurring in the second project, so I don't know if NSZombieEnabled will apply to the second project?

How do I solve this? Especially as I it only happens on the device (even goes as planned on the simulator), and it is in the second project?

EDIT: [This is the method](https://github.com/davedelong/StackKit/blob/master/Classes/_SKRequestBuilderTags.m#L50-70) where the EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs, on line 62, on sortRange.lower –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that one of your objects is autoreleased before you are trying to access it. As the iPad has less memory than the computer you are running it on it get's released faster so that's why it's not available. Try NSLog both objects just before the line you are getting the error and see wich one of them is the problem and than trace back to it's origin and retain it somehow. Also don't forget to release it after you are done using it. Some example code would be useful.

Comment: I NSLog the objects immediately after they are returned by method that seemingly creates them and I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Try returning the object as `return [yourObject retain];`. Does that help? If yes don't forget to do `[yourObject release];` after you are done with them.

Comment: The problem is that the method returns a struct which you can't retain, it contains 2 objects though. Also the method that returns the struct is in a category extension of NSPredicate, and it seems I cant step into that method when debugging.

Comment: What the code that creates the 2 said objects? Can you post it here? Can you access the source code of it?

Comment: [This is the method](https://github.com/davedelong/StackKit/blob/master/Classes/_SKRequestBuilderTags.m#L50-70) where the EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs, on line 62, on `sortRange.lower`

Comment: You said that it breaks on line 62. That means that `sortRange.lower` it's not the problem because on line 61 it uses it to check if it's different than `SKNotFound`. My guess is that something goes wrong with `[self query]`. Can you log that before line 60?

Comment: Well I tried loggin sortRange.lower, and then it moved to that line. I also tried logging `[self query]` and `[self requestSortDescriptor]` both of which were not nil. But `p` was nil. (This is what I expected). btw, SKNotFound is defined as `nil`.

Comment: If you say that `p` is empty that means that `sortRange ` will be nil because any method that is called on nil will return nil. `[self query]` is a NSMutableDictionary as far as I can see and you cannot add nil to a NSMutableDictionary. Try to find out why `p` is empty and maybe that will give you a clue of what's happening.

Comment: No `p` is meant to be empty, at least in this case. If sortRange.lower is nil then when you slog it it should print (null). Also the if statement on line should return false as SKNotFound is defined as nil.

Comment: What would be the type of sortRange.lower? It would be an object? Can you add non-object values to dictionary by using setObject:obj forKey:key method? I hope that would not be an issue here.

Comment: I guess p should not be nil? if so, you are setting struct to nil. SKRange sortRange = nil can behave different to platform. as sortRange is first initialized as {random memory value, random memory value}. [p rangeOfConstantValuesForLeftKeyPath:[[self requestSortDescriptor] key]] should return a valid SKRange struct, which is not the case if p is nil.

Answer (score 1):

NSZombieEnabled only works on the simulator, not on the device, so it's probably hiding the problem. Run Product > Analyze (⇧⌘B) for clues. It's harder to say more without looking at the code. As Mihai says, your objects are probably over released, which is the most common cause of EXC_BAD_ACCESS.